# does limiting the host in my mux prevent CSRF attacks?

Tags: security, browser, web, csrf, csrf-protection

If I have my mux router limited to accept requests only from my domain, then will that prevent a CSRF attack?

For example in my golang server I have all requests go through my baseRouter:

```
baseRouter := mux.NewRouter().Host(`{sub:.*}.myDomain.com`).Subrouter()
```

So wouldn't this mean that if a user was on another site some.attacker.net that posted a request off to my server, then it would simply get a 404 returned for every request because my server won't process any requests from other domains, thus preventing a CSRF attack, or am I basing this on some misconception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because when `attacker.example.com` POSTs to `mysite.example.org` the host header will be set to `mysite.example.org`.

[Gorilla has a package to enable you to protect against Cross Site Request Forgery](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/csrf).

Comment: what if instead of `.Host("mysite.example.org")` I used `.Header("referrer", "mysite.example.org")`, would that not limit access to my inner web server routes to only those coming directly from mysite?

Comment: Yes, that would work, although [referrer is considered a weaker form of protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header). Also, if there are any open redirect vulnerabilities on your site these can defeat referrer checking. [`Origin` is better although it is inconsistent](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/91190/8340). Also bear in mind that some people disable referrer client-side for privacy purposes.